# Add bluetooth mouse to Windows 10 after removing

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10

I accidentally removed my Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse from the Windows 10 Bluetooth settings.  Now it doesn't appear at all in Manage Bluetooth Devices.  How to get it back?

Comment: Luckily it doesn't involve programming, but that does mean you have to ask this over at SuperUser

Comment: Oh got it - thanks I did that http://superuser.com/questions/962419/add-bluetooth-mouse-to-windows-10-after-removing-it